# Calibrate Routes giving Error 000443 using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, routing, linear-referencing

I am trying to calibrate routes using points along them. Those points are represent counts of hikers per hour.

I have done a spatial join between my route layer and my points to have the RouteID in common. Some points do not match any route.

Then, I tried to use the **[Calibrate Routes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000004000000)** tool but the attribute table of the new shape is exactly the same as the one of the Route shape. And if I try again I get an error 000443.

Would that be due to the fact that some of my points do not match any route?

Should I calculate an average value of the counts for each point before I use the calibration?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that **[Calibrate Routes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000004000000)** is the right tool for what you are trying to do but, in any event, **Error 000443** is documented **[here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp00000021000443)** where it says:

> **Description**
>
> This error occurs when one or more features are rejected by the Create
>   Routes process. A text file is created in the temporary file path to
>   store information about those features. This file contains a full
>   description of these issues.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Review the log file to examine the errors encountered during route
>   creation to see how to proceed. One of the more common errors you
>   might encounter is "The measure value is outside of the output M
>   domain." This error occurs when an m-value being assigned to a route
>   feature falls outside the allowable m-range as defined by the
>   m-domain. To resolve this, ensure the m-domain defined for the output
>   route feature class is appropriate for your data. For more information
>   on the m-domain, see **[Defining the measure properties of your m-coordinates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00390000000p000000)**.

If you are not sure whether this is the right tool, then rather than investigate more deeply, my recommendation would be to ask a new Question (not as part of this one) to try and describe using a diagram or two precisely what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the Calibrate Routes tool is that it takes an existing line and then defines the space in time or ground measurement between the calibration points as they relate to the line itself. This is so that later, when you place points along a route, they correlate with whatever environment is being reproduced.

For example, one might be able to say that a hiker covered x amount of meters between two calibration points, and then average a speed that the hiker is walking at to determine when they may have stopped for a break.

I'm not sure how the Calibration tool itself handles points that are not on the route line.

For the purposes stated in the question, I agree with the other answers. It's necessary to have a clear picture of the question one is asking first and foremost. As the Calibration tool is only part of the Routing set, it does not seem best suited for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here.  More info would be useful.

However, in your question you mention shapefiles.  Shapefiles are from a file based dataset.  If you are using linear referencing you have to be working from a geodatabase.

I suggest you go back to the beginning and import your shapefile (line) and shapefile (point) into a geodatabase and then try the linear referencing again.  Also make sure that you are using the same coordinate system in both files and checking your environment settings to make sure the output will be in the same coordinate system.  I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I would suggest using a projected coordinate system rather than a geographic one (as we're trying to measure distances here, effectively).

Give that a shot and let me know how you get on.